# PHP regular expression to add a href=tel: in front of each telephone number

Tags: php, regex

I am new to php regular expressions, though could you please help me to create a valid php regular expression to add "a" tag for each telephone number.

Each phone number has this mask:

```
+39 0000 00 00 00
```

This should be like:

```
<a href="tel:+39 0000 00 00 00">+39 0000 00 00 00</a>
```

I have spent a lot of time searching for it on the web, so I decided to ask this question here.

Comment: We are not here to write the code for you. Can you show us some code you have already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to add some suff around:

```
preg_replace('/(\+[0-9 ]{16})/', '<a>$1</a>', "+39 0000 00 00 00")
```

the `\+` is for the + and `[0-9 ]{16}` exact 16 chars for numbers and spaces if you have some time 15 or less you can wirte `{min,max}` for the amount of chars exclude the +